# 'You were pigged'

Tags: american-english, british-english, slang, pejorative-language

> A devastated student flew 400 miles to meet her lover in Amsterdam only to be told she was the victim of a cruel **'pull a pig'** prank.
>
> Sophie Stevenson, 24, from Stoke, forked out £350 on a flight after being invited to the Dutch capital by her Jesse Mateman, 21, who she met in Barcelona in August.
>
> But when Miss Stevenson arrived at her hotel she received a text message telling her it was all a ruse and she had been stood up by the heartless Dutchman who told her, **'You've been pigged'**.
>   *[Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4960848/Devastated-student-victim-cruel-pull-pig-joke.html)*

Absolutely new slang for me but luckily the excerpt clearly tells me what “to be pigged” means.

I'm guessing that it is related to the informal BrEng expression, **[pig out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pigged)**: To eat ravenously; gorge oneself: “pigged out on cake”,  and according to *Macmillan Dictionary*, [*to eat an extremely large amount of food*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/pig-out)

Oxford Dictionaries lists a long list of idioms citing the four-hoofed  **[Suidae](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pig)** but no mention of the idiom used in the *The Daily Mail*

- Any idea as to when ***to be pigged*** was coined?
- Is the phrase also used in the US? If not what would be its equivalent? *Prank* doesn't seem to cut the mustard.

Comment: Means nothing to me (British speaker), and even with the story I'm not sure precisely what it means; and I can't see the relevance of the phrase you've mentioned. My immediate thought is that it might be a _Dutch_ expression, which the trickster used in English.

Comment: The original article here (it's been updated since): [Devastated student](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sh6_RJGI9MsJ:www.theunknownbutnothidden.com/devastated-student-flew-400-miles-meet-lover-victim-cruel-pull-pig-joke/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Comment: Maybe "pull a pig" is more common among English-speakers living an Amsterdam, than among those living in England?

Comment: Like you I had never seen that wording before, but my reading of the context and colocations says, contrary to you, it is likely to mean prank or ruse and have nothing to do with eating a lot.

Comment: @Mitch if you look at the link below my question and NVZ's answer the expression also refers to overweight/unattractive girls. I guessed the verb "pig" was a throwback to "pig out" but there's also the idiom "put lipstick on a pig".  I like to see if there are connections. If there aren't there aren't. In the US do they have anything similar?

Comment: @Mari-LouA oh...NVZ's answer seems plausible, that pig's are also a metaphor for ugly and this is a very very particular kind of prank.

Comment: @ColinFine: Dutch speaker here, there's no commonly known Dutch saying. However,  I do remember a (US) TV show where some of the "cool" guys were wooing ugly and/or fat girls, inviting them to go out with them, and then cruelly revealing that it's a contest about inviting "the ugliest pig possible", which the guys drove home by wearing pig masks. I completely forget which show this is from, but I seem to recall seeing similar plotlines a couple of times, usually revolving around calling the girls pigs.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: As others have said, "pig" in this context simply means unattractive person, as in the phrase "pig ugly". No relation to "pig out".

Comment: I'd say she "bought a pig in a poke."

Comment: In the US, the term [hogging](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hogging) is common enough that I've heard it a couple of times. I've never heard of someone "being hogged" though.

Comment: @default.kramer Well surely we can apply the normal rules of English morphology to go from one to the other.

Comment: Existing answers seem to rely on the victim being observed by others in on the prank - I don't see any evidence of that happening. I wonder if it's related to the gender stereotype, e.g. "all men are pigs"; this seems out of line with the perpetrator using the phrase himself though. Unable to find a reference to support this, hence commenting instead of answering.

Comment: I've never heard this specific phrase before but "to pull" means to persuade someone to attach themselves to you romantically - usually on a night out. A pig is slang for a fat person, so you can see where this is going.

Comment: Good grief, what a bunch of assholes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Deriving as it does from "Pull-A-Pig", which is described as a "drinking game" by Clare Longrigg in the [26 Aug 1993 issue of *The Guardian* ("Poison ivy and the wallflowers")](https://www.newspapers.com/clip/14311088/poison_ivy_and_the_wallflowers_26_aug/), 'she is/was/has been pigged' probably originated sometime historically proximate to that publication.

In brief, "Pull-A-Pig...is a drinking game in which men compete to see who can pick up the ugliest woman" (op. cit.). The 'pig' in question, thus, is a derogatory slang reference to an "unattractive woman". *OED* describes that sense of 'pig' as "chiefly US"; however, I found no evidence that "Pull-A-Pig" is known in the US, and use of 'pull' in the sense of to "pick up (a partner), esp. for sexual intercourse; to seduce" is described by *OED* as "Brit. slang".

'Pigged' in the use quoted in the question ("you've been pigged") is likely to have sprung from a play on a slurred pronunciation of 'picked' ("she was picked/pigged"), a slur perhaps thought amusing by the semi-adolescent males who might find such a game appealing. Alternatively, of course, 'pigged' may simply have sprung organically from the linguistic demand to name the objects of the "Pull-A-Pig" 'game'.

The historically parallel and equivalent name of the US drinking 'game' (more appropriately called a *crime*, viz. ["Intentional Infliction of Emotional Distress"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentional_infliction_of_emotional_distress)), if it existed, might have been, variously, "Dig-A-Dog" (midwest) or "Skin-A-Skank" (east coast), although more broadly "Pick-A-Pig" might have been adopted coast-to-coast.

Comment: +1 Wow! How did you find that? Impressively, the definition only appeared on [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pull%20a%20pig) 10 years later.

Answer (score 24):

Seems like an unusual expression, which means, the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pull%20a%20pig) might be the only source at the moment to explain it. In 2013, a user,  awbladerunner,  defined it as:

> Pull a Pig is a game where a group of guys go out and they win the game by pulling the ugliest looking woman.

And so, *to be pigged* means to be the victim of the prank. The "winner" is the one who gets the "ugliest" girl, 'pig' presumably being metonymy for 'ugly'.

According to [*The Sun*](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/4642247/pull-a-pig-game-josie-cunninghams-pull-the-pig-dating-site/), the expression was possibly popularized from a dating site called *Pull The Pig* [started in 2014 by Josie Cunningham](http://www.thedebrief.co.uk/news/celebrity/josie-cunningham-s-got-a-dating-site-for-ugly-women-20140917678).

> The site was apparently aimed at "average-looking women" though currently the website is blank and says it is being updated.

Comment: A [local newspaper](http://www.shorehamherald.co.uk/news/offbeat/woman-left-stranded-by-holiday-lover-after-pull-a-pig-prank-1-8188908) (of all sources) also corroborates what the pig is that's pulled.

Comment: I think the missing link here is the semantic creep from "fat" to "ugly."

Comment: In American English, this is called a "dogfight". There was a movie about it with that name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogfight_(film)

Comment: OED gives for ‘pig’: ‘A woman. In early use apparently as an endearment. In later use *derogatory* (chiefly US): a female prostitute; a promiscuous or unattractive woman.’ So the creep seems to be from sexually available to undesirable rather than from fat to ugly.

Comment: You might note that "pull" means to successfully approach or hit on someone e.g. at a bar or club; it's a familiar phrase in the UK but not in the US.

Comment: @casey: at first glance I thought you were referring to the Dutch guy as a "semantic creep". On second thought, given the nature of the question, this seems highly apt.

Answer (score 1):

The answer presents itself from the definition of the prank as "Pull a Pig". Wherever it originates the use of it can be contracted as it is in the example to mean "You've been pranked": "You've been pigged". Heartbreaking and costly trick to play on anyone.

Comment: I think it's a bit more specific than that.